# Tell jest to ignore firebase/* when testing

Tags: reactjs, firebase, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm trying to test visual aspects of a react component, when rendering my component in a test my tests fail due to an "unexpected token export" that I believe is coming from firebase.

I don't wish to test firebase, though it is preventing my tests from running.

I'm getting the below error:

```
/Users/me/Desktop/Projects/Personal/myapp/node_modules/firebase/database/dist/index.esm.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){export * from '@firebase/database';
                                                                                      ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

    > 1 | import { update, ref, get } from 'firebase/database';
```

If possible - I would simply like to "ignore" firebase, so I can test my component.

Any help would be great - I've scoured the internet for the last few hours and nothing seems to work, so I think I'm looking in the wrong places.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I exclude files from Jest watch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40486567/how-can-i-exclude-files-from-jest-watch)

Comment: Did you fix this issue? Banging my head here over the past few days and can't find a solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add folder path in the "**jest**" object in your `package.json` file

```
"testPathIgnorePatterns": ["src/firebase" or "dist/src/firebase"]
```

Read more [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testpathignorepatterns-arraystring)