# How to include jest tests from ignored path / run tests from excluded path?

Tags: jestjs, ts-jest

My project structure:

```
    src
     - foo
       - test A
       - test B
       - test C
     - bar 
       ...
```

I ignore `foo` and not run testcases from there [like discussed in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40486567/how-can-i-exclude-files-from-jest-watch/51312509#51312509):

```
    testPathIgnorePatterns: ['src/foo/'],
```

but because of reasons I want to run `src/foo/test B`

How can I achieve that?
Neither of the following worked.

```
    testMatch: [
      '**/*.test.{ts,tsx,js,jsx}',
      'src/foo/test B',
    ],

testPathIgnorePatterns: ['src/foo/'],
```

```
  testMatch: [
    '**/*.test.{ts,tsx,js,jsx}',
    '!src/foo/**/*',
    'src/foo/test B',
  ],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content of this array is interpreted as regex:

```
testPathIgnorePatterns: ['src/foo/']
```

therefore it's possible use a negative lookahead and specify which testfiles / paths which shall be executed:

```
testPathIgnorePatterns: [
    'src/foo/(?!test B)', 'src/bar/(?!some/other/path/test Y)'
]
```